# NoSuchMethodException when using Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: spring, jar, scheduled-tasks, war, autowired

I am using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor. It is defined in a spring bean. As guided in the documentation, the class has only 1 constructor which gets the TaskExecutor as a parameter.
When I am running the project as a standalone jar using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, everything works correctly. The TaskExecutor is created and executed.
Now I wanted to connect the Jar project to my web application (war). I added the required dependency in my web application POM file and used some of the jar project code. 
There are no compilation errors, and mvn package also passes. But when I start the server, I get the following error (full trace below):
    org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [me.somesome.task.SyncTaskPool]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me. somesome.task.SyncTaskPool.()

The constructor that I have in the SyncTaskPool class is initiating the TaskExecutor. If I add a constructor with no arguments, the server starts and the empty constructor is executed (and not the parameterized constructor)
I am using Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE
In the jar application context the task executor is defined as:

```
<bean id="syncTaskPool" class="me.somesome.task.SyncTaskPool">
    <constructor-arg ref="myTaskExecutor" />
</bean>
```

The SyncTaskPool  constructor:

```
package me.somesome.task;

import me.somesome.taskServiceFacade.ServiceFacade;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SyncTaskPool  {    

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SyncTaskPool .class);

    // this field is being set by Spring. It is defined as a bean in the application context
    private TaskExecutor adTaskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceFacade serviceFacade;

    public SyncTaskPool (TaskExecutor adTaskExecutor) {
        this.adTaskExecutor = adTaskExecutor;
    }
```

}

The full error:

```
2015-01-11T11:52:31,300 [localhost-startStop-1] _[1;31mERROR_[m org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adSyncTaskPool' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ad-mgmt/WEB-INF/lib/component-stats-sync-impl2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/me/somesome/task/SyncTaskPool.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [me.somesome.task.SyncTaskPool]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.somesome.task.SyncTaskPool.<init>()
    at    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [me.somesome.task.SyncTaskPool]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.somesome.task.SyncTaskPool.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.somesome.task.SyncTaskPool.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3069) ~[?:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2165) ~[?:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
```

The jar application context:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd"  >

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="me.somesome" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.somesome" />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"> 
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="syncTaskPool" class="me.somesome.task.SyncTaskPool">
        <constructor-arg ref="myTaskExecutor" />
    </bean> 

    <task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
    <task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
    <task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

    <bean id="catalogFacade" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://127.0.0.1:6080/ad-mgmt/remoting/catalog" />
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.somesome.mgmt.facade.ICatalogFacade" />
        <property name="overloadEnabled" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="trackingAggregationService" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://127.0.0.1:5080/tracking-manager2/remoting/trkmgr" />
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="me.somesome.track.trackingmanager.facade.TrackingManagerFacade" />
        <property name="overloadEnabled" value="true" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The War application context:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-   context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.somesome" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="me.somesome" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: What is the version of your Spring libraries? Maybe the method is removed from that library

Comment: It is also annotated with `@Component` which will have it detected by component-scanning. There is no default constructor and the constructor you have isn't annotated with `@Autowired` so it doesn't know what to do. Either remove `@Component` or the xml configuration and put `@Autowired` on the constructor.

Comment: @M.Deinum - That did the job! I removed the Component annotation and defined it in the xml. Each time that I needed to use the class, I defined it also in the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the SyncTaskPool bean was defined twice. The first was Component annotation definition:

```
@Component
SyncTaskPool
```

The second was an xml definition:

```
<bean id="syncTaskPool" class="me.somesome.task.SyncTaskPool">
    <constructor-arg ref="myTaskExecutor" />
</bean>
```

I removed the Component annotation and I removed the autowired annotation from the SyncTaskPool definitions.